# Sending Data to a CompactLogix PLC from an Android App

Tags: android, communication, plc

Just making a rather simple Time Station app for my company, writing in java, and I'm pretty new to android studio.  I have employee names in a string array, but i need those to reference a unique number for each employee, then when pressing a "send" button, that unique number is received by the ethernet module on a CompactLogix l35-e.  It has a static IP, so it should work the same as just sending to a website, correct? Once I receive the data on the plc, I can handle the interpretation of data and the rest of the databasing.  If i could figure out how to send a single bit to the plc, i think i could figure it out from there.
MainActivity Java
    package com.aes.aestimestation;

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.numbers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int position, long id){
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent){
}
```

}

Comment: Posting some current code might help people help you better.

Comment: basically rather than using the Toast, i need the spinner selection to reference a number, then when press the "send" button, send data to a static IP

Answer (score 0):

Allen-Bradley CompactLogix/ControlLogix PLCs use the Ethernet/IP protocol.  You can find out more about Ethernet/IP by visiting the ODVA (standards organization) [page about Ethernet/IP](https://www.odva.org/Technology-Standards/EtherNet-IP/Overview) and by reading their [Ethernet/IP Quick Start for Vendors Handbook (PDF)](https://www.odva.org/Portals/0/Library/Publications_Numbered/PUB00213R0_EtherNetIP_Developers_Guide.pdf).

You probably want to use "Explicit Messaging" for your application.

If working with Ethernet/IP sounds too complicated, you can use some middleware to act as the interface between your application and the PLC.  Rockwell's RSLinx functions in this way, interfacing with the PLC and providing a DDE or OPC server for your application to interface with.